# Can I provide style for buttons on window created in a third party library?

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

Is it possible to style buttons on a window that is created and shown by a third party library?

The buttons in question rely on the default style of `Button` like this:

```
<Button Name="CancelButton"
        DockPanel.Dock="Right"
        Height="23" Width="75" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        Margin="4" 
        IsCancel="True" 
        Content="_Cancel" />
```

Since the window is controlled by the third party library the only thing I have "access to" is the type name of the window.

Can I provide a local default button style for that window that will override the application style for button without altering the XAML of the window?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.
The style of a control is based on the scope of the style declared.

For example:

Values assigned to properties within the actual element will override the style declared from the resources of a parent element.

Comment: I understand but the buttons use the default style which is defined at the application level but I want to use a different style for buttons on this particular window. But I can not change the XAML.